# asp.net MemberShip could not be found

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

I created the aspnetdb.mdf tables and sp's inside my db on a remote hosting sql box.
Membership Provider is connecting remotely and working fine when I run it from my dev local box. But when I try it on the live site I get the error below.
Here are  my web.config settings.

```
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=remoteIP;Initial Catalog=admin_TeacherClassSchedule;User ID=developer;Password=blah" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

 <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
      <providers>
        <add
          name="SqlProvider"
          type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
          connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
          applicationName="/"
          enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
          enablePasswordReset="true"
          requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
          requiresUniqueEmail="false"
          passwordFormat="Encrypted"
          maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
          passwordAttemptWindow="10" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add
        name="SqlProvider"
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
        connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
        applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
```

Server Error in '/TCS' Application.
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Default Membership Provider could not be found.

Source Error:

Line 42:            
Line 43:        
Line 44:     
Line 45:       
Line 46:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=1.1.1.1;Initial Catalog=dbname;User ID=blah;Password=blah" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
  <providers>
    <add
      name="SqlProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
      connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
      applicationName="/"
      enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
      enablePasswordReset="true"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
      requiresUniqueEmail="false"
      passwordFormat="Encrypted"
      maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
      passwordAttemptWindow="10" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SqlProvider"
        connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
        applicationName="/"
        type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </providers>

  </profile>
<roleManager defaultProvider="SqlProvider" enabled="true" >
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add
      name="SqlProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
      connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
      applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a `<clear />` in front of your add on membership.  I normally clear out all of my providers before I add them, just in case.